# launchctl plist has a stderr that talks about how getcwd operation not permitted so how do I fix it?

Tags: catalina, launchd, plist

**TLDR for those who googled and found this**

In Catalina, `launchd` can't read files or run scripts located inside your `~/Documents` folder. Just avoid putting your scripts there and rewrite your scripts not to read files in `~/Documents`. Creating a new file or symlink will work, though. See the [answer below](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/393509/32815) for details.

---

## Original question

I came via this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62114538/80353) to help me create a script that will update a symlink every day.

And there was an [article](https://medium.com/@chetcorcos/a-simple-launchd-tutorial-9fecfcf2dbb3) it links to teaching me how to use plist and launchctl

SO this is my plist `com.journal.today.plist` which is installed in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>

    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.journal.today.plist</string>

    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>

    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/Users/kim/journals/stderr.log</string>

    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/Users/kim/journals/stdout.log</string>

    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
      <key>PATH</key>
      <string><![CDATA[/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]]></string>
    </dict>

    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/kim/journals</string>

    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>./makeTodaySym.sh</string>
    </array>

  </dict>
</plist>
```

When i check the stderr I saw the below

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent
  1 bash: ./makeTodaySym.sh: Operation not permitted
```

stdout.log was empty

How do I solve this?

---

My original script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

date=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %A"`
folder="." # replace with full path to desired folder
file="$folder/$date.md"

if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
    touch "$file"
    echo "Created file: $file"
fi

ln -sf "$file" "$folder/today.md"
echo "Created link to file: $file"
```

---

After trying out jksoegaard answer, the last part of my plist looks like this:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>/Users/kim/journals/makeTodaySym.sh</string>
</array>
```

---

Latest change after taking jaume comment

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>/bin/bash</string>
  <string>/Users/kim/journals/makeTodaySym.sh</string>
</array>
```

---

Latest change

in the bash script

```
folder="$1" # replace with full path to desired folder
```

in the plist

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>/bin/bash</string>
  <string>/Users/kim/journals/makeTodaySym.sh /Users/kim/journals</string>
</array>
```

---

I have also tried

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>/bin/bash</string>
  <string>/Users/kim/journals/makeTodaySym.sh</string>
  <string>/Users/kim/journals</string>
</array>
```

And now I get this

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
/bin/bash: /Users/kim/journals/makeTodaySym.sh: Operation not permitted
```

---

thanks to @jaume with great patience, he/she/they have helped me get to the point where I realized that the only thing that worked was to move away from the Documents folder in Catalina.

I did find this link https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250719819?answerId=251683647022#251683647022 suggesting to create a fake bash clone, but I didn't try.

Also a big thank you to @nohillside

One useful thing I learn is to load and unload plist without restarting laptop

first unload

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.test.today.plist
```

then load

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.test.today.plist
```

Comment: Does the user under which the launchd job executes have write access to the directory?

Comment: Also, is this Catalina? Did you grant disk access?

Comment: @nohillside thanks. I have updated the question with answer to your questions

Comment: Could you add a trace option to the shebang line (for `bash` and `zsh`, that option is `-x`, like `#!/bin/bash -x`.) and post the command that causes the error? Please add some lines before the offending command for context, if necessary.

Comment: regarding the user: where did you install the plist? If in your own library, it runs as you, if in /Library it runs as root.

Comment: also, please don't add a bunch of questions to the post, let's work these things out in the comments

Comment: Noted abt adding the bunch of questions in post. To answer your question, I installed under `~/Library/LaunchAgents` so as myself

Comment: Do you really assign "." in your script? Can you use the full path there?

Comment: I used @jksoegaard answer so now it looks like this <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/Users/kim/journals/makeTodaySym.sh</string>
    </array>

Comment: I have changed the plist as instructed by adding the `/bin/bash`. but do I have to restart my laptop? is there an easier way to trigger the plist without restarting? I'm multi tasking with this SO question while doing some other work.

Comment: Yes, run `launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.journal.today.plist` to unload it, edit the file, and then run `launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.journal.today.plist` to load it.

Comment: Tried. stderr.log shows `shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
/bin/bash: /Users/kim/journals/makeTodaySym.sh: Operation not permitted`

Comment: WHen I type `/bin/bash /Users/kim/journals/makeTodaySym.sh` directly in the iTerm, it works perfectly
`Created file: ./2020-06-10 Wednesday.md
Created link to file: ./2020-06-10 Wednesday.md`

Comment: I still get this after the unload and then load `shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
/bin/bash: /Users/kim/journals/makeTodaySym.sh /Users/kim/journals: No such file or directory` Again I have tried the command directly in iTerm `/bin/bash /Users/kim/journals/makeTodaySym.sh /Users/kim/journals` And it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109142/discussion-between-kim-stacks-and-jaume).

Comment: @KimStacks I could get the `plist` to work within the Documents folder, I will explain the exact procedure in the answer, it involves giving `bash` full disk access.

Comment: Sounds like the same solution I found on the Apple website but I will wait for your solution

Comment: @KimStacks After quite a bit of research, I found out that there's a better solution. If you move the script outside of `~/Documents` and edit the `.plist` file accordingly, everything should work, see my answer for details. Could you try it and report back?

Comment: Move the script outside of ~/Documents and change the working directory to the new location and remove launchd full disk access, even if the acted upon parameter is a folder inside Documents will still work. Yes!  @jaume

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Analysis

After a long chat session, it turns out that the root of the problem was that `bash` can't fully access the Documents folder. The OP had shortened the actual path for `makeTodaySym.sh`: instead of being located in `/Users/kim/journals`, the script resides in a subfolder of `~/Documents`.

The Documents folder is sandboxed, as explained [in this Apple document](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/sec35dd877d0/1/web/1):

> In macOS, data in critical areas is itself sandboxed — which ensures that users remain in control of access to files in Desktop, Documents, Downloads and other areas from all apps, whether the apps attempting access are themselves sandboxed or not.

and `bash` can't read its contents from within the `.plist` file.

### Two solutions

**Place the script outside of `~/Documents`**

Interestingly enough, although `bash` can't read the contents of the Documents folder, it can **write** to it.

So one solution is to move `makeTodaySym.sh` outside of `~/Documents`. For instance, if placed in `/Users/kim/bin/makeTodaySym.sh`, this should work:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>/bin/bash</string>
  <string>-c</string>
  <string>/Users/kim/bin/makeTodaySym.sh /Users/kim/Documents/Apps/CompanyLevelApps/OILD/16-journals</string>
```

(Tested on macOS 10.15.5 Catalina.)

**Grant full disk access to `bash`**

Another solution is give `bash` full disk access. Just add `/bin/bash` to System Preferences>Security & Privacy>Privacy>Full Disk Access.

Note that even with full disk access, permissions would prevent `bash` from reading arbitrary files in the file system, but you have one fewer level of protection.

(Tested on macOS 10.15.5 Catalina.)

### Two suggestions

I'd suggest that you do the following two changes to your configuration:

**Remove reference to working directory**

I've noticed that setting a working directory in the `.plist` file:

```
<key>WorkingDirectory</key> 
    <string>/Users/kim/Documents/Apps/CompanyLevelApps/OILD/16-journals</string>
```

causes this error:

> `job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted`

Your script doesn't need the `WorkingDirectory` key to successfully create the symlink, so you may want to remove it to get rid of the error.

**Create symlink with relative path**

Your script creates the symlink:

```
ln -sf "$file" "$folder/today.md"
```

with an absolute path:

> `today.md@ -> /Users/kim/Documents/Apps/CompanyLevelApps/OILD/16-journals/2020-06-10 Wednesday.md`

To may want to use:

```
ln -sf "$(basename "$file")" "$folder/today.md"
```

instead to create a relative symlink that is easier to read:

> `today.md@ -> 2020-06-10 Wednesday.md`

### Full path in plist file

It's important to note that **providing the full path** for `makeTodaySym.sh` (as explained in [jksoegaard's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/392798/32815)) was a necessary change for the `.plist` to work properly, as relative paths are not supported.

Comment: i think the bounty needs a min of 24 hrs before awarding. thank you!

Comment: awarded. thank you @jaume this is one of the best experiences I've ever had on SO!

Comment: @KimStacks Hi Kim, that's very kind, I'm happy I could help! I've expanded the TLDR section in your answer to include additional information and a link to my answer. Feel free to edit it if you think it can be improved.

Comment: It’s all good. Thanks for expanding on the TLDR

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this:

```
<string>./makeTodaySym.sh</string>
```

so that you refer the whole path to the file. That could for example be like this:

```
<string>/Users/kim/journals/makeTodaySym.sh</string>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have replaced it and unloaded and reloaded the plist. But it doesn't seem to create the new symlink. And after I wiped the stderr.log I still ahve the same error message after I relaunched the plist